# VS2022 Build Error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

Was a WPF/DevExpress .net 4.8 Framework project, that I upgraded to Net7 with the ".Net Up[garde Assistant" - that went really smoothly.

Everything builds except for this error:

```
Error LC0000 'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)'
```

From googling it seems to be the Aero or Aero2 theme assembly. I've scoured my code and xaml and cannot find any direct references to it. Have ensured that the Net 6&7 Desktop runtimes are installed, as well as the SDK's. Rebooted etc.

Can't see it referenced in the package list either.

Windows env is Windows 10 Pro.

All windows updates applied, cleared the package cache

Stuck - any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: That's a DLL used for Wpf controls.

Answer (score 1):

Generated a bare bones Net7 Project with DevExpress components, which built and ran fine. I compared the project files - my updated one had a lot of fluff compared to the base one.

Removed items one by one, eventually came down to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Licenses.licx" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Compiled and ran fine after that, weird.

Contents of the License file was DevExpress component licenses, removed it, doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your Wpf csproj should look something like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>

      <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

Did you miss out that UseWPF tag?